# String Manipulation in R: drop between , and .

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector called `Names` which obviously contains names of people, both male and female, of all ages.

My task is to retain each person's full name. The format of the raw vector `Names`  is as follows:

```
'last name','title'.'first name'
```

Examples:

```
Names <- c("Jackson, Mr. James", "Johnson, Miss. Elizabeth")
```

How do I keep everything (full name) other than the titles ("Mr.", "Miss.", etc)?

Comment: `gsub` would do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex to match the whole thing: ([see on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KBG6W4/2))

```
(.*),.*\. (.*)
```

Group 1 matches last name, group 2 matches first name.

You can then replace each match with `\2 \1` for `firstname lastname` or replace with `\1 \2` for `lastname firstname`

**Code**

```
gsub("(.*),.*\. (.*)", "\2 \1", yourArray)
```

Comment: There are many many other titles, maybe better to replace everything between `,` and `.` with space?

Comment: do you need `perl=TRUE`?  And not sure about a case-sensitivity flag: in standard R it would be `ignore.case=TRUE` (but maybe there's a case-insensitivity flag rolled into the regex when `perl=TRUE`?

Comment: Updated my answer. I guess `perl=TRUE` is not necessary, this will work in any regex engine. Updated answer doesn't need flag anymore.

Comment: Thanks @ Croutonix and everyone who commented to provide further insights!!